# Not inserting data in database - grails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, insert

I don't get any errors but my app is not saving data in the database.

here's profitTable.gsp

```
                <g:form controller="dailyProfit" action="save" >
                    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dailyProfitInstance, field: 'date', 'error')} required>
                        <label for="date" >Date</label>
                        <g:datePicker name="date" precision="day"   value="${dailyProfitInstance?.date}"  />
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dailyProfitInstance, field: 'profit', 'error')} required>
                        <label for="profit">Profit</label>
                        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                        <g:field name="profit" value="${fieldValue(bean: dailyProfitInstance, field: 'profit')}" required=""/>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save btn btn-default " value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </g:form>
```

Here's my controller

package samplegrailsapp

```
class DailyProfitController {
    def scaffold = DailyProfit
    def index() { 
        render(view:"profitTable");
    }

    def save() {
       // Date myDate = params.date('test', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        def dailyProfit = new DailyProfit(params)
        params.date = params.date_year + "-0" + params.date_month + "-" + params.date_day
        println params.toString();
        dailyProfit.save()
        render(view:"profitTable");
    }
}
```

This is my domain class

```
package samplegrailsapp

import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
class DailyProfit {
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Date date;
    double profit; 

    static constraints = {
        date (blank:false, nullable:false, validator: {value, object ->
           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
           Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
           cal.setTime(new Date());
           cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
           cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
           cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
           cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if(!(cal.getTime().before(value) || cal.getTime().equals(value))){
                return false;
            } 
        })
        profit (blank:false, nullable:false, validator: {value, object ->
                if (!value.toString().matches(/^([1-9]{1}[0-9]*\.{0,1}\d{0,2}|0\.[0-9]{1,2}|0)$/) ) return false;
        })     
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        //id generator:'assigned', name:'date'
        id column: 'date', name: 'date', generator: 'assigned'
    }

}
```

ANd this is the data inside params.

```
[date_day:10, profit:8, date_year:2015, date_month:8, date:2015-08-10, create:Create, action:save, format:null, controller:dailyProfit]
```

When I checked the logs, this is what I get:

> Hibernate: select dailyprofi_.date, dailyprofi_.profit as profit0_
>   from daily_profit dailyprofi_ where dailyprofi_.date=? Hibernate:
>   insert into daily_profit (profit, date) values (?, ?)

Why cant it read the data from params?? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What happens when you change `dailyProfit.save()` to `dailyProfit.save(flush: true)`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that the dailyProfit.date takes a date object but you were supplying a string date. I also faced the same problem. Below is the code :

```
def save() {
       // Date myDate = params.date('test', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        def dailyProfit = new DailyProfit()
        def updatedDate = params.date_year + "-0" + params.date_month + "-" + params.date_day
        dailyProfit.date = sdf.parse(updatedDate);

        dailyProfit.profit = params.profit

        dailyProfit.save()
        render(view:"profitTable");
    }
```

Do let me know if it worked.

Happy Coding.